# How to change the date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, datetime-format

Table:

```
Dates (nvarchar)
==
23/02/2009 (dd/mm/yyyy)
24/02/2009
25/08/2009
28/12/2011
....
```

I want to change the date form like this (yyyymmdd)

Tried query

```
select cast(dates as datetime) from table1
```

Showing error

ЮArithemetic expression overflow

```
select Convert(char(10), dates, 112) from table1
```

Showing the same value 23/02/2009

The above query is not working.

Expected Output

```
20090232
20090224
20090825
20111228
...
```

How to make a query?

Comment: If those are **dates** -ö then **WHY** are they stored as `varchar` ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(datetime, '23/02/2009',103),112)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since these are stored as string data then you might as well just use the string functions to give you what you want.

First to give you a valid date

```
select 
    cast(SUBSTRING(dates,4,2) + '/' + left(dates,2) + '/' + right(dates,4) as datetime) NowItsADateTime
from DateTable
```

And second, what you asked for.

```
select right(dates,4) + SUBSTRING(dates,4,2) + left(dates,2) as YYYYMMDD
from DateTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,dates)+DATEPART(m,dates)+DATEPART(d,dates) FROM table1
```

You can get more information on this link:
[sql-server-dates](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2009/05/datepart-dateadd-datediff-sql-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 102)[Dates] from tablename
```

Take a look on this link: http://www.technoreader.com/SQL-Server-Date-Time-Format.aspx